# I am new to C# development.Someone please give me sample solution with textfile to read/write with SQL

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am new to C# development.Someone please give a sample solution with text file to read/write with SQL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask], before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 0):

```
FXCalculation.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace EmployeeValidator
{
class FXCalculation
{
   public void ProcessData( string sourcefolder,string sourcefilename,stringerrorfolder,string errorfilename,string archievefolder,string archievefile,stringsqlcon)
    {

        //call all the method inside this
        // throw user defined exception “FXCalculationException if folder or files doesn’t exists
        FXCalculation fxcalculation = new FXCalculation();
        List<Trade> trades = new List<Trade>();
        trades = fxcalculation.ReadAlltextfromfile(sourcefolder,sourcefilename);
        List<Trade> validtrades = fxcalculation.PickValidTradeDetails(trades, errorfolder, errorfilename);
        fxcalculation.SendValidTradeDetailsToDB(validtrades, sqlcon);
        List<FxRate> fxrates= fxcalculation.CalculateFXRate(sqlcon);
        SaveFxRatestoDB(fxrates, sqlcon);
    }
public List<Trade> ReadAlltextfromfile(string sourcefolder,string sourcefilename)
    {
        List<Trade> trades = new List<Trade>();
        //read all the text from file
        //return it in a list
        try
        {
            trades = File.ReadLines(sourcefolder + sourcefilename)
                .Select(i => i.Split(','))
                .Select(g => new Trade()
                {
                    tradeId = g[0],
                    ISIN = g[1],
                    tradedate = g[2],
                    maturitydate = g[3],
                    currency = g[4],
                    amount = g[5],
                    tradetype = g[6],
                    schemename = g[7]

                }).ToList();
            return trades;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

    public List<Trade> PickValidTradeDetails(List<Trade> list,stringerrorlogfolder,string errorlogfile)
    {

        List<Trade> validtrades = new List<Trade>();
        List<Trade> invalidTrades = new List<Trade>();
        bool isvalid = true;
        //get the valid details based on below conditions and return it in list
        //call method SendInvalidTradingdetailsToLog() for invalid details

        //tradeId should starts with “TR” and not be null
        //ISIN should starts with “INSI” and followed by 3 numeric digits
        //trade date should be in format(mm/dd/yyyy)
        //maturity date should be in format(mm/dd/yyyy) and maturity years should be greater than 5 from trade date
        //schemename should not be numeric
        //tradetype should not be null,
        //Currency should be 3 digits
        //Amount should be numeric and not null
        Regex IsTradeId = new Regex(@"^[TR][0-9]+$");
        Regex IsISIN = new Regex(@"^[INSI][0-9]{3}$");
        Regex Isscheme = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
        Regex Iscur = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]{3}$");
        Regex IsAmo = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$");
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            DateTime oparsed, dparsed;
            if ((item.tradeId.Substring(0,2) == "TR" && item.tradeId != string.Empty) &&
               (item.ISIN.Substring(0,4) == "INSI" && Regex.Match(item.ISIN, @"\d{3}$").Success) &&
               (DateTime.TryParseExact(item.tradedate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out oparsed) &&
               (DateTime.TryParseExact(item.maturitydate, "MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out dparsed) &&
               (Regex.Match(item.schemename,@"^[a-zA-Z]+$").Success))))
                {
                if((DateTime.ParseExact(item.tradedate,"MM/dd/yyyy", newCultureInfo("en-US")) -
            }

            if (!IsTradeId.IsMatch(item.tradeId) || !IsISIN.IsMatch(item.ISIN) || !Isscheme.IsMatch(item.schemename) || !Iscur.IsMatch(item.currency) || !IsAmo.IsMatch(item.amount))
            {
                isvalid = false;
            }
            if (item.tradetype == null || item.tradetype==string.Empty)
            {
                isvalid = false;
            }
            DateTime outdatetime,outdatetime1;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(item.tradedate, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None,out outdatetime))
            {
                isvalid = false;
            }
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(item.maturitydate,new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None,out outdatetime1))
            {
                isvalid = false;
            }
            if (!isvalid)
            {
                invalidTrades.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                validtrades.Add(item);
            }
        }
        if (invalidTrades.Count()>0)
        {
            SendInvalidTradingdetailsToLog(invalidTrades, errorlogfolder, errorlogfile);
        }

        return validtrades;
    }
 public bool SendInvalidTradingdetailsToLog(List<Trade> trades,stringerrorfolder,string errorfilename)
    {
        //Send invalid details to error log folder with filename extensions ErrorLog_mm/dd
        //return true if the file is saved successfully
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(errorfolder + errorfilename + "ErrorLog_mm/dd"))
        {
            foreach (var item in trades)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(item.tradeId + ',' + item.ISIN + ',' + item.tradedate + ',' + item.maturitydate + ',' + item.currency + ',' + item.amount + ',' + item.tradetype + ',' + item.schemename);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool SendValidTradeDetailsToDB(List<Trade> trades,string slconn)
    {
        // save the values inside the validtrade list
        // save the details to DB to the TradingDetails_Table
        int i = -1;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(slconn);
        foreach (var item in trades)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into TradingDetails_Table Values(@TradeId,@ISIN,@TradeDate,@MaturityDate,@Currency,@Amount,@Tradetype,@Schemename)", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TradeId", item.tradeId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISIN", item.ISIN);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TradeDate", item.tradedate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaturityDate", item.maturitydate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Currency", item.currency);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", item.amount);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tradetype", item.tradetype);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Schemename", item.schemename);
                con.Open();
                i=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }
        }

        //if its saved successfully
        if (i > -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }



    public List<FxRate> CalculateFXRate(string sqlconn)
    {
        List<FxRate> Fxrates = new List<FxRate>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlconn);

        // get the trade details from the DB where Tradetype = “FX”
        // calculate FX rate based on the below conditions
        // If Currency = “USD” then CalculatedFxrate = amount * 0.5
        // If Currency = “BPS” then amount *0.6
        // If Currency = “EUR” then amount *0.7
        // If Currency = “GER” then amount *1
        using (SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("select TradeId,Currency,Amount From TradeDetails_Table Where Tradetype='FX'",con))
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                FxRate fx = new FxRate();
                fx.tradeId = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                fx.currency = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                fx.amount = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                switch (fx.currency)
                {
                    case "USD":
                        fx.appliedFxrate = Convert.ToString(0.5);
                        fx.calculatedFxRate = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(fx.amount) * 0.5);
                        break;
                    case "BPS":
                        fx.appliedFxrate = Convert.ToString(0.6);
                        fx.calculatedFxRate = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(fx.amount) * 0.6);
                        break;
                    case "EUR":
                        fx.appliedFxrate = Convert.ToString(0.7);
                        fx.calculatedFxRate = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(fx.amount) * 0.7);
                        break;
                    case "GER":
                        fx.appliedFxrate = Convert.ToString(1);
                        fx.calculatedFxRate = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(fx.amount) * 1);
                        break;
                }
                Fxrates.Add(fx);
            }

        }
        return Fxrates;
            //it in a list Fxrates
    }

//0.5, 0.6… appliedFxRate


public void SaveFxRatestoDB(List<FxRate> list,string SqlConn)
    {
        //Save the calculatedFXrates along with tradeId, currency and amount in the table FxRates_Table
        // return true if it is saved successfully
        int i = -1;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlConn);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into FxRate_Table Values(@TradeId,@Currency,@Amount,@AppliedFxrate,@CalculatedFxRate)", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TradeId", item.tradeId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Currency", item.currency);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", item.amount);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppliedFxrate", item.appliedFxrate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalculatedFxRate", item.calculatedFxRate);
                con.Open();
                i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }
        }

    }



public void Copyfiletoarchieve(string sourcefolderWithName,stringdestinationfolderWithName)
        {
        //Copy the file from input folder to the achieve folder with file extension “Filname_Processed”
        // If the file already exists delete it and add the new one
        if (File.Exists(destinationfolderWithName))
            File.Delete(destinationfolderWithName);
        File.Copy(sourcefolderWithName, destinationfolderWithName);
        File.AppendText(destinationfolderWithName + "Filname_Processed");
    }


}
}
Program.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EmployeeValidation
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
          /*
           * Pass the file path, file names and connection string if any in this method alone.
           * Do not hardcode in any other methods
           */
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC233649;Initial Catalog=DBEmployeeValidation;Integrated Security=True");
        EmployeeValidator empValidator = new EmployeeValidator();
        empValidator.ProcessData(@"C:\Users\153239\Desktop\Input File\", "Emp_122014.xml", connection);

    }
}
}


EmployeeValidator.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;

namespace EmployeeValidation
{
public class EmployeeValidator
{
    /*
    * Do not remove the attached TestProject. It is meant for auto evaluation of your source code.
    * Do not attach any test classess to the attached test project.
    * Do not attach any new test projects.
    * You are not required to write any automated test cases. You are supposed to write only the code.
    */

    public void ProcessData(string xmlFilePath, string xmlFileName, SqlConnectionconnection)
    {

        EmployeeValidator empVal = new EmployeeValidator();
        List<Employee> lstemp = new List<Employee>();
        lstemp = empVal.ReadAllEmployeesFromXmlFile(xmlFilePath, xmlFileName);

        lstemp = empVal.PickValidEmployees(lstemp);       

        empVal.SaveValidEmployeesToDB(lstemp, connection);         

    }
    public List<Employee> ReadAllEmployeesFromXmlFile(string xmlFilePath, stringxmlFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
            XElement xelement = XElement.Load(xmlFilePath + xmlFileName);
            IEnumerable<XElement> allEmployees = xelement.Elements();

            foreach (var allEmployee in allEmployees)
            {
                empList.Add(new Employee()
                {
                    EmployeeId = allEmployee.Element("EmployeeId").Value,
                    EmployeeName = allEmployee.Element("EmployeeName").Value,
                    EmailId = allEmployee.Element("EmailId").Value,
                    DateOfJoining = allEmployee.Element("DateOfJoining").Value
                });
            }
            return empList;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {

            throw new EmployeeValidatorException(ex.Message);

        }

    }

    public List<Employee> PickValidEmployees(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
        Regex IsNumeric = new Regex(@"^\D+$");
        Regex IsAlphaNumeric = new Regex(@"\W+$");
        Regex IsvalidEmail = new Regex(@"^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,17}))$");

        empList = employees.Select(x => employees.Find(
            m => m.EmployeeName != null && m.EmployeeName != string.Empty
                && !IsNumeric.IsMatch(m.EmployeeId.ToString()) && !IsAlphaNumeric.IsMatch(m.EmployeeName)
                 )).Distinct().ToList();

        return empList;
    }

    public void SaveValidEmployeesToDB(List<Employee> employees, SqlConnectionconnection)
    {
        string query = @"Insert into SBA.Employees(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,DateOfJoining,EmailId)
                                        Values(@EmployeeId,@EmployeeName,@DateOfJoining,@EmailId)";
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            foreach (Employee emp in employees)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", emp.EmployeeId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", emp.EmployeeName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", emp.EmailId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfJoining", emp.DateOfJoining);                   
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
}
Employee.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EmployeeValidation
{
public class Employee
{
    /*
    * Do not modify the return types of the below properties
    *
    */

    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string DateOfJoining { get; set; }
}

// Do not add new constructors
}

Employeevalidatorexception.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EmployeeValidation
{

public class EmployeeValidatorException : Exception
{
    public EmployeeValidatorException()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public EmployeeValidatorException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
}
FxRate.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EmployeeValidator
{
class FxRate
{
    public string tradeId { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string appliedFxrate { get; set; }
    public string calculatedFxRate { get; set; }
}
}

Trade.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EmployeeValidator
{
   public class Trade
{
    public string tradeId { get; set; }
    public string ISIN { get; set; }
    public string tradedate { get; set; }
    public string maturitydate { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string tradetype { get; set; }
    public string schemename { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EmployeeValidation
{
public class Employee
{
    /*
    * Do not modify the return types of the below properties
    * 
    */

    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string DateOfJoining { get; set; }
}

// Do not add new constructors
}




Program.cs
public class Program
    {
    public static void Main()
    {

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC233649;Initial Catalog=DBEmployeeValidation;Integrated Security=True");
        EmployeeValidator empValidator = new EmployeeValidator();
        empValidator.ProcessData(@"C:\Users\a\Desktop\Input File\","Emp_122.xml", connection);

        }



EmployeeValidator.cs

public class EmployeeValidator
    {

    public void ProcessData(string xmlFilePath, string xmlFileName, SqlConnection connection)
    {

        EmployeeValidator empVal = new EmployeeValidator();

        List<Employee> lstemp = new List<Employee>();

        lstemp = empVal.ReadAllEmployeesFromXmlFile(xmlFilePath, xmlFileName);

        lstemp = empVal.PickValidEmployees(lstemp);        

        empVal.SaveValidEmployeesToDB(lstemp, connection);          

        }





EmployeeValidator.cs

 public List<Employee> ReadAllEmployeesFromXmlFile(string xmlFilePath, string xmlFileName)
        {

        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

        XElement xelement = XElement.Load(xmlFilePath + xmlFileName);

        IEnumerable<XElement> allEmployees = xelement.Elements();

        foreach (var allEmployee in allEmployees)

        {

            empList.Add(new Employee()

            {

                EmployeeId = allEmployee.Element("EmployeeId").Value,

                EmployeeName = allEmployee.Element("EmployeeName").Value,

                EmailId = allEmployee.Element("EmailId").Value,                   

                DateOfJoining = allEmployee.Element("DateOfJoining").Value

            });               

        }

        return empList;

        }




EmployeeValidator.cs

 public List<Employee> PickValidEmployees(List<Employee> employees)
        {

        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

        Regex IsNumeric = new Regex(@"^\D+$");

        Regex IsAlphaNumeric = new Regex(@"\W+$");

        Regex IsvalidEmail = new Regex(@"^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,17}))$");

        empList = employees.Select(x => employees.Find( m => m.EmployeeName != null && m.EmployeeName != string.Empty
                && !IsNumeric.IsMatch(m.EmployeeId.ToString()) && !IsAlphaNumeric.IsMatch(m.EmployeeName)
                 )).Distinct().ToList();

        return empList;

    }
(or)

      extractuniquelist = employees.GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();
        foreach (var emp in extractuniquelist)
        {
            if ((IsNumeric.IsMatch(emp.EmployeeName)) && (emp.EmployeeId != "") && (IsAlphaNumeric.IsMatch(emp.EmployeeName)) && (emp.EmployeeName != "") && (email.IsMatch(emp.EmailId)))
            {
               empList.Add(new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId,
                    EmployeeName = emp.EmployeeName,
                    EmailId = emp.EmailId,
                    DateOfJoining = emp.DateOfJoining
                });
            }
            }


EmployeeValidator.cs

  public void SaveValidEmployeesToDB(List<Employee> employees, SqlConnection connection)
        {
        string query = @"Insert into SBA.Employees(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,DateOfJoining,EmailId) Values(@EmployeeId,@EmployeeName,@DateOfJoining,@EmailId)";

        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))

        {

            foreach (Employee emp in employees)

            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", emp.EmployeeId);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", emp.EmployeeName);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", emp.EmailId);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfJoining", emp.DateOfJoining);       



                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

        }

        connection.Close();

        }




Read from TEXT file

 public List<Employee> ReadValuesfromTextfile(string fpath, string fname)
        {
        List<Employee> readedValues = new List<Employee>();

        if (Directory.Exists(fpath))
        {
            if (File.Exists(fpath + fname))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fpath + fname))
                {
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string readline = sr.ReadLine();
                        if (readline != null && readline != "")
                        {
                            readedValues.Add(new Employee
                            {
                                EmployeeId = readline.Split(',')[0],
                                EmployeeName = readline.Split(',')[1],
                                EmailId = readline.Split(',')[2],
                                DateOfJoining = readline.Split(',')[3]
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return readedValues;
        }



Read From XML file

public List<Employee> ReadFromXmlFile(string FilePath, string FileName)
        {

        List<Employee> emplist = new List<Employee>();

        if (Directory.Exists(FilePath))

        {

            if (File.Exists(FilePath + FileName))

            {

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FilePath + FileName);

                XmlSerializer xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Employee>), 

new XmlRootAttribute("Employees"));

                emplist = (List<Employee>)xSerializer.Deserialize(sr);

            }

        }

        return emplist;

        }



Read From Database

public List<Employee> savefromDBtoTextfile(SqlConnection connetion)
        {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        List<Employee> selectlist = new List<Employee>();

        string query = "select * from SBA.Employees";

        connetion.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connetion))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);
        }
        connetion.Close();

       foreach (DataRow emp in dt.Rows)
        {
            selectlist.Add(new Employee
            {
                EmployeeId = emp["EmployeeId"].ToString(),
                EmployeeName = emp["EmployeeName"].ToString(),
                EmailId = emp["EmailId"].ToString(),
                DateOfJoining = emp["DateOfJoining"].ToString()
            });
        }

        return selectlist;
        }




Write to Text File


 public void WritetoTextFile(List<Employee> writelist, string FilePath)
        {

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(FilePath + "newtxtfile.txt"))

        {

            foreach (var emp in writelist)

            {

                sw.WriteLine(emp.EmployeeId + " " + emp.EmployeeName + " " +emp.EmailId + " " + emp.DateOfJoining + " ");

            }

        }

        }




Write to XML File


public void writeXmlfile(List<Employee> epmlist)
       {

        var fileName = @"K:\redir\Desktop\TestDotnet\Input File\TestFile.xml";

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))

        {

            XmlSerializer xmlsr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Employee>), new XmlRootAttribute("Employees"));

            xmlsr.Serialize(sw, epmlist);

            sw.Flush();

            sw.Close();

        }

        }


Insert into Database


 public void SaveValidEmployeesToDB(List<Employee> employees, SqlConnection     connection)
        {

        string query = @"Insert into SBA.Employees(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,DateOfJoining,EmailId) Values(@EmployeeId,@EmployeeName,@DateOfJoining,@EmailId)";

        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))

        {

            foreach (Employee emp in employees)

            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", emp.EmployeeId);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", emp.EmployeeName);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", emp.EmailId);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfJoining", emp.DateOfJoining);       



                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

        }

        connection.Close();

}
```